# keep DIV displayed if mouse hover over it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code (take from another question somewhere here):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#profile_dropdown").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
        $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeIn("slow");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var someElement = $("#profile_dropdown");
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 650);
        //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
        someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
    });
});
```

It works as expected, however - I can't figure out how to keep the `#profile_dropdown_content` shown if the mouse is moved over it. And how to make it fadeOut if the mouse moves out of course...

Any ideas?

Comment: I have lots of ideas. Can you set up a jsfiddle showing what the issue is?

Comment: is #profile_dropdown_content a child of #profile_dropdown?

Comment: Could you post your HTML code along with this?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - sorry, I am working on it, but it seems that it's too complex for the fiddler...

Comment: basically I need the same behaviour as the profile dropdown on top of this page where it shows the reputation, votes etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest the `#profile_dropdown_content` inside the `#profile_dropdown` container and use the hover event.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UsWYq/1/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#profile_dropdown").hover(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
        $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function(){
        var someElement = $("#profile_dropdown");
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 650);
        //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
        someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="profile_dropdown">
    <div class="inner">Hover Me</div>
    <div id="profile_dropdown_content">Display Me</div>
</div>
<div id="profile_dropdown"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#profile_dropdown {
    background:whitesmoke;
    float:left;
}
#profile_dropdown .inner {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
#profile_dropdown_content {
    display:none;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

**Option 2**

Another thing you could do is CSS3 transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezxm5/

```
#profile_dropdown {
    background:whitesmoke;
    float:left;
}
#profile_dropdown:hover #profile_dropdown_content {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
    height:100px;
}
#profile_dropdown .inner {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
#profile_dropdown_content {
    opacity:0;
    background:red;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, height 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, height 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, height 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, height 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in, height 0.4s ease-out;
}​
​
```

Comment: thank you, that's where I am now basically... what i need to add is to keep the red one shown when you move the mouse over it... and hide it when mouse leaves...

Comment: Oh so the red will keep displaying while it's being hovered over too?

Comment: thanx @brenjt, this was the best solution... I considered it already before, but I thought there would be some other way...

Comment: @Michal you are welcome. There is also the CSS3 transition option you could try. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the elements in another `div` then bind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions to the wrapper.

**Mock HTML**

```
<div id="profile_wrapper">
    <div id="profile_dropdown">Profile Dropdown</div>
    <div id="profile_dropdown_content">This is some information about me.  I write code all day long.</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#profile_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
        $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeIn("slow");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        var someElement = $("#profile_dropdown");
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#profile_dropdown_content").fadeOut("slow");
        }, 650);
        //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
        someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H7Hvf/1/